# Loading an image saved to the Documents Directory only works once, then never loads again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I am writing an app where the user chooses images to use in the app, which will be saved and then loaded into a table view. I am saving the data of the image to the documents directory, and then saving the PATH OF THE DATA as an attribute to a Realm object. I am then trying to use the saved path to load its associated image.

Right now, I am saving (successfully I think, because it loads the image once...) like this:

```
let image = imageField.image
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData?

let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let writePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(uuid).png")

imageData?.write(toFile: writePath, atomically: true)

ownerPhoto.photoPath = writePath  //setting the path attribute of the object
ownerPhoto.owner = newOwner       //creating a relationship between the image and the owner

newOwner.title = titleTextField.text!
newOwner.ownerDescription = ownerDescriptionField.text!
newOwner.photos.append(ownerPhoto)

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(newOwner)
    realm.add(ownerPhoto)
//I am creating and saving both the new Owner profile and their first photo at the same time here
}
```

After this is saved, it then segues to a tableView. This tableView will show a list of owners, with the photo we just saved as each cell's background. I am trying to do this with:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! tableCellTripTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row

    let firstPhoto = ownersArray[row].photos[0].photoPath
    //This is an array of all of the Owner objects of the app
    //firstPhoto will be equal to the path (String) that we just saved above

    cell.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: firstPhoto)
    return cell
}
```

Presently, the cell shows the saved image ONLY after it is first saved. Once I press save and it segues to the tableView, the newly created Owner will have their background, but ONCE I RESTART THE APP, the cell has no background. Why is it disappearing? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT FOR ANYONE READING THIS IN THE FUTURE:

To fix this issue, do not save the path. Just the filename (uuid). So do:

```
ownerPhoto.photoPath = "\(uuid).png"
```

Then at cellForRowAt function:

```
let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(firstPhoto)

cell.backgroundImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never store a full path. An app's sandbox changes over time. Just store the file name. When you want to get the full path to the file, calculate it at runtime based on the stored filename and the current value for the Documents folder.