# FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:) showing nil after saving string to filepath

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

When I create a filePath for an image then write it to the filePath, it doesn't load the image in the `loadImageViewController`

saveImageViewController:

```
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let documentPath = documentsURL.path
        let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("profile_image.png")

    do {
        let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentPath)
        for file in files {

            if "\(documentPath)/\(file)" == filePath.path {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
            }
        }

    } catch {
        print("Could not add image from document directory: \(error)")
    }

    do {
        if let pngImageData = profilePicImageView.image!.pngData() {
            try pngImageData.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
        }
    } catch {
        print("couldn't write image")
    }
    entity.profilePicPath = filePath.path
```

loadImageViewController:

```
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: entity.profilePicPath!) {
        let contentsOfFilePath = UIImage(contentsOfFile: entity.profilePicPath!)
        cell.entityImage.image = contentsOfFilePath
    }
```

I am saving the file path as a string through core data.

Comment: Never store full paths. The app's container moves all of the time. Just store the filename and build the full path every time.

Comment: Why was the reopened? What's wrong with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046462/loading-an-image-saved-to-the-documents-directory-only-works-once-then-never-lo?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I must have missed that one because that is the exact answer I needed. Thank you.